# discord.py How do I turn this into a multiple-winner gway command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to turn the code I've right now to also work with multiple winners.

```
@commands.command()
    async def gstart(self, ctx, time1, winners : str, *, prize):
        authorURL = ctx.author.avatar_url

        
        
        winners = int(winners.replace("w",""))
        if winners > 30:
            await ctx.send("Max winners is 30")
            return
        channel = ctx.channel
        guild = ctx.guild
        time = self.convert(time1)
        current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        time_added = datetime.timedelta(seconds = time)
        future_time = current_time + time_added

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{prize}', description=f'React with <a:party_tada:809202936600199209> to enter!\nHosted by {ctx.author.mention}', timestamp=future_time, color=random.randint(0, 0xfffffe))
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{winners} winner(s) | Ends at ")
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('<a:party_tada:809202936600199209>')

        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        
        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))

        
        try:
            n = 0
            for _ in range(winners):
                winner = random.choice(users)
                users.pop(users.index(winner))
                await ctx.send(f'{winner.mention} has won the giveaway for **{prize}**\n{msg.jump_url}')
                await ctx.guild.fetch_member(winner.id)
                emb = discord.Embed(title="You won!", description=f"You have won the giveaway for [{prize}]({msg.jump_url}) in **{guild}** - {channel.mention}", colour=discord.Color(0x4CAF50))
                emb.set_footer(text=" Congratulations!")
                await winner.send(embed=emb)
                n = n + 1
                

            
            em = discord.Embed(title=f'{prize}', description=f'Winner(s) {winner.mention}\nHosted by {ctx.author.mention}', timestamp=future_time, color=discord.Color(0x2F3136))
            em.set_footer(text=f"{winners}w | Ended at ")
            em.set_author(name="This giveaway has ended", icon_url=f"{authorURL}")
            await msg.edit(embed=em)
            emb1 = discord.Embed(title=f'Your giveaway has ended!', url=msg.jump_url, description=f"[__**Desktop Friendly URL**__]({msg.jump_url})\nYou have **{n} winner(s)**!\n `1`: {winner.mention} - [{winner.id}]", colour=discord.Color(0xFFF857))
            await ctx.author.send(embed=emb1)

        except:
            em = discord.Embed(title=f'{prize}', description=f'Could not determine a winner\nHosted by {ctx.author.mention}', timestamp=future_time, color=discord.Color(0x2F3136))
            em.set_footer(text=f"{winners}w | Ended at ")
            em.set_author(name="This giveaway has ended", icon_url=f"{authorURL}")
            await msg.edit(embed=em)
    
    @gstart.error
    async def gstart_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error,commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send('<:redTick:814774960852566026> Incorrect usage: `gstart <time> <winners> <prize>`\nAn example: `,gstart 10s 1w Discord Nitro`')
        elif isinstance(error,commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send('<:redTick:814774960852566026> You are missing the `Giveaway_Manager` role to do that.')
```

However this is not optimal for mutliple winners. It chooses multiple winners and send them into the channel where the giveaway was hosted in, sure. But, is there any way to edit the

```
await ctx.send(f'{winner.mention} has won the giveaway for **{prize}**\n{msg.jump_url}')
```

part

so that if there is only one winner, it only mentions one. And if there's more, it mentions all winners with a comma in between, like so:

```
await ctx.send(f'{winner.mention}, {winner2.mention} etc has won the giveaway for **{prize}**\n{msg.jump_url}')
```

And also for the

```
emb1 = discord.Embed(title=f'Your giveaway has ended!', url=msg.jump_url, description=f"[__**Desktop Friendly URL**__]({msg.jump_url})\nYou have **{n} winner(s)**!\n `1`: {winner.mention} - [{winner.id}]", colour=discord.Color(0xFFF857))
            await ctx.author.send(embed=emb1)
```

part to send multiple listed winners?
I am thinking of creating a dict and storing the winners in it but I don't know how to.

Help is very much appreciated :)

[A view of what the output right now is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SP73.png)

Blockquote

Comment: Use an `if`-statement to check if there are multiple winners

Comment: @stijndcl That works, and that is also what I did, a for-loop instead of an if-statement. If I put it in an if-statement, I still need a variable that can change the embed description so it fits the amount of winners

Comment: Can you explain that a bit better? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Basically, the bot can already check if there is multiple winners.

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/728191011318136862/814943548666675220/unknown.png

Thats a link with an image of what the output would be for the embed for one winner.

And if there's more than one, I want the bot to list it aswell. E.g. 
```
You have 2 winners
2. @example ID: [1234567890] when theres 2 etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you just want to create a string with all members that won. You can do this using `string.join()` with a `list comprehension`.

```py
# "1 winner" & "2 winnerS"
plural = "winners" if winners != 1 else "winner"

# Create a string of all the winners of the form "1. UserName ID: [UserId], ..."
winner_string = "\n".join(f"{i + 1}. {user.mention} ID: [{user.id}]" for i, user in enumerate(users))
await ctx.send(f"You have **{winners} {plural}**\n{winner_string}")
```

If this is not what you were looking for, feel free to point it out.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Any way to change this part also to multiple winners？

await ctx.send(f'{winner.mention}, {winner2.mention} etc has won the giveaway for **{prize}**\n{msg.jump_url}')

Now my code chooses a winner every time in the loop, and sends
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/809545109695234118/815138906382401556/unknown.png

as many times as there are winners. is there any way to also put the winners string in there? so instead of that it becomes
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/809545109695234118/815139813157634069/unknown.png

Comment: Yes, do something similar, also using a list of winners/strings & using string.join. You should be able to figure that out on your own from my answer above, it's practically the same. If it solved your issue, you should mark it as correct.